# OxyPlot navigation

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, oxyplot

I am having difficulty with `OxyPlot`. When I load my data on the graph it is perfectly fine, but when I navigate to detail activity and then navigate back to main activity, I still have graph but no plot data in it, it is just empty.

When I navigate back to the main activity, I see that `PlotView` becomes null, but `Lineseries` still keeps data.

**ViewModel**

For simplicity I have just created a simple `ObservableCollection` which contains the same groups of plot points (graph shape) repeated a few times.

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    PlotModel GeneratePlotPoints()
    {
        var mo = new PlotModel();
        var s1 = new LineSeries()
        {
            Color = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
            MarkerSize = 6,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White,
            MarkerFill = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
            MarkerStrokeThickness = 1.5
        };

        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 10));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 40));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 20));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(60, 30));
        mo.Series.Add(s1);

        return mo;
    }

    List<PlotModel> GenerateGraph()
    {
        var graphPlots = new List<PlotModel>();
        int counter = 0;

        while (counter < 10)
        {
            graphPlots.Add(GeneratePlotPoints());
            counter++;
        }

        return graphPlots;
    }

    public List<PlotModel> GraphPlots => GenerateGraph();
}
```

**Layout**

Your main layout with the RecyclerView.

```
<MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource GraphPlots"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/mycardview" />
```

The `mycardview` layout template. Note that the use of the point is used to tell Mvx to bind to the whole model (in this case the PlotModel)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <oxyplot.xamarin.android.PlotView
     android:id="@+id/Plot"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     local:MvxBind="Model ."/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**View**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
   var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MainView, null);
   HasOptionsMenu = true;
   var cardRecyclerView = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.myRecyclerView);
   if (cardRecyclerView != null)
   {
       cardRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = false;
       var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);
       cardRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    return view;
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your ViewModel life cycle, set your model to null before creating it.

```
  protected override void Load()
    {
        plotModel = null;
        plotModel = GeneratePlotPoints();
    }
```